# How to dump emmc of Asus Zenfone 3?

Tags: data-recovery, asus-zenfone-3

I am trying to dump the emmc of my Zenfone ze552kl. The bootloader is locked. I tried to dump the emmc from edl mode but it required a programmer to do so and none of the programmers I found online worked. Some of the programmers just didn't work and some rebooted the device. I can access fastboot and adb when I use "fastboot oem adb_enable". Is there any way for me to dump the emmc of this device without unlocking the bootloader? Or is there a way to unlock the bootloader without wiping on this device?

Comment: If the device boots into Android you could try to find a vulnerability that allows you to gain root permissions and potentially allows you to directly dump the whole flash memory. BTW: What do you want with a eMMC dump? Most likely it will be encrypted.

Comment: @alecxs I can't dump from adb as I don't have root access.

Comment: @Robert I can't boot to android but I can boot to recovery.

Comment: unfortunately without proper firehose programmer there is nothing you can do to by-pass bootloader lock. do you have *backup user data* option in recovery?

Comment: Sadly, there is no option like that. Is there anything else that I could do? I heard that when you switch to 9006 mode, the device shows up as a disk. But I don't know how to enter that mode without a programmer.

Comment: you mean something like this? i doubt it works for encrypted device https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3570178

Comment: Yes, something like that. But my device doesn't switch to DLOAD mode. I also found out that erasing the aboot partition might force the device to switch to DLOAD mode. But I don't know how I can erase it without unlocking the bootloader.

Comment: you should be able to enter proper mode from test points. do not erase aboot (bootloader) you will brick your device and make it unrecoverable (because you don't have programmer, fastboot is your only way to flash)

Comment: When I use an EDL cable I can only enter the 9008 mode which requires a programmer. Are there other test points to enter DLOAD mode?

Comment: search for collections like
[romprovider.com](https://romprovider.com/download-prog_emmc_firehose-qcom-phone-cpus),
[firmware27.com](https://www.firmware27.com/2017/06/collectionprog-emmc-firehose-prog-ufs.html),
[leakite.com](https://www.leakite.com/collection-qualcomm-emmc-programmer-files),
[github.com](https://github.com/programmer-collection),
[tuserhp.com](https://www.tuserhp.com/2018/02/prog-emmc-firehose-ufs-firehose.html),
[firmwarego.com](https://firmwarego.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=folder&id=2288)

Comment: found [prog_emmc_firehose_8953_ddr.mbn](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bricked-asus-ze552kl-dead-qualcomm-hs-usb-qdloader-9008.3603643/page-4#post-84752847) (chinese post)